# For the Call of Cthulhu LCG, what is the release order of the expansions?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-lcg

I would like to know where I can find a list of all the expansions to the core set and the release dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BoardGameGeek.com](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/40270/call-of-cthulhu-the-card-game#moreinfo) lists all the Asylum Pack Expansions, along with their order of release. The database does have a field for **Release Date**, but usually it is blank with only the year of release noted.

-1) **Forgotten Lore:** Spawn of Madness, Kingsport Dreams, Conspiracies of Chaos, Dunwich Denizens, At the Mountains of Madness, Ancient Horrors

-2) **The Summons of the Deep:** Spawn of The Sleeper, The Horror Beneath the Surface, The Antediluvian Dream, The Terror of the Tides, The Thing from the Shore, The Path to Y'ha-nthlei

-3) **The Dreamlands:** Twilight Horror, In Memory of Day, In the Dread of Night, The Search for the Silver Key, Sleep of the Dead, Journey to Unknown Kadath

-4) **The Yuggoth Contract:** Whispers in the Dark, Murmurs of Evil, The Spoken Covenant, The Wailer Below, Screams from Within, The Cacophony

-5) **The Rituals of the Order:** The Twilight Beckons, Perilous Trials, Initiations of the Favored, Aspirations of Ascension, The Gleaming Spiral, That Which Consumes

-6) **Ancient Relics:** The Shifting Sands, Curse of the Jade Emperor, The Breathing Jungle, Never Night Into Tartarus, Shadow of the Monolith

-7) **Revelations:** Written and Bound, Words of Power, Ebla Restored, Lost Rites, The Unspeakable Pages, Touched by the Abyss

**Deluxe Expansions**: Secrets of Arkham, The Order of the Silver Twilight, Seekers of Knowledge, The Key and the Gate Terror in Venice

FFG have now retired Asylum Packs for Call of Cthulhu and will now be releasing deluxe expansions every 4 months instead, beginning with the Seekers of Knowledge.